# Are placeholders types of non-type template parameters interchangeable in case of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider a simple example:

```
int x;

template <template <auto> class TT>
struct Foo {
   void foo() {
      TT<(x)> tt;
      static_cast<void>(tt);
   }
};

template <decltype(auto)>
struct Bar { };


int main() {
    Foo<Bar> foobar;
    foobar.foo();
}
```

[[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ONvvMTCTqW7Aenm) seems to deal with the idea of `decltype(auto)` placeholder despite the use of `auto` in template template parameter declaration without a problem.

[[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7THzOxieKVDoi1Gk) on the other hand - not very well:

> prog.cc:6:13: error: the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression

---

As usually - which behaviour is expected according to standard? Or maybe everything is possible and the code is ill-formed (this time I suppose not but cannot rule it out definitively)?

PS. Sorry for breaking one of the compilers again ;)

Comment: I don't see how specifying `(x)` for a template parameter, where `x` is a variable, is valid for any kind of a template. Last time I checked a template parameter can only be a type or a constant.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik for `decltype(auto)` it is resolved to a referenceto a variable as long as the variable has a linkage of course (last time I checked this was actually valid ;))

Comment: Well, this one deserves an upvote, then.

Comment: So you would expect `Bar` to be instantiated with a template type of `int&` and a template parameter of reference to `x`, which is a constant expression even though `x` itself isn’t?

Comment: @DanielH Basically this is a test if the template is interpreting `auto` as `decltype(auto)` in its instantiation or not. I do not prejudge if it is expected...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You could basically always have had a non-type template parameter of reference type...

Comment: GCC isn't complaining for the fact that you mix `auto` and `decltype(auto)`. It's saying that you cannot use `x` that way for it's not constant. Turn `x` in a `const int` and [it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RXJEoX8fHaAxJIYH). The fact is that for clang `decltype(auto)` rules, `auto` rules for GCC instead. Both of them simply _accept_ the mix.

Comment: @skypjack the question is which one is correct :) I preparated the example just to show the idea. I could static_assert with reference checking but this test seemed to be more appropriate.

Comment: @W.F. Yeah, the question is good indeed. My only concern is that it seems GCC doesn't accept the mix as you describe it. The problem is the other one around instead. That's all. ;-)

Comment: gcc gives a slightly different error message, `‘int x’ is not const`, without an extra indirection thrown in the mix; with simply "`int x=0; template <decltype(auto)> class Foo {}; Foo<x> bar;`" Throwing parenthesis around it, making it `Foo<(x)>` makes it happy. Hmmm....

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, yes. `Foo<x>` is ill-formed but `Foo<(x)>` is well-formed. That's a given, and doesn't really help answer this question.

Comment: @skypjack maybe accepting the mixes has something to do with accepting any non type template parameterin place of auto for template templates in c++17

Comment: @W.F. Just fyi, even though you already accepted the answer, I think it wasn't quite right before and I changed it.

Comment: @Barry of course improvements are always welcome. I was kind of surprised of your previous interpretation about `Foo<Bar>`, but do not pretend to be a language lawyer :) Thanks for your answer. I think I found yet another clang bug with `decltype(auto)` in template template parameter not related to this one so they obviously have to repair things much more deeply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original answer here had `Foo<Bar>` ill-formed, I actually now think it's well-formed. But ultimately, clang bug based.

---

<s>I actually think even `Foo<Bar>` is ill-formed.</s> The new rules, following [P0522](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) are that:

> A *template-argument* matches a template *template-parameter* `P` when `P` is at least as specialized as the *template-argument* `A`

where:

> A template *template-parameter* `P` is at least as specialized as a template *template-argument* `A` if, given the following rewrite to two function templates, the function template corresponding to `P` is at least as specialized as the function template corresponding to `A` according to the partial ordering rules for function templates ([temp.func.order]). Given an invented class template `X` with the template parameter list of `A` (including default arguments):
>
> - Each of the two function templates has the same template parameters, respectively, as `P` or `A`.
> - Each function template has a single function parameter whose type is a specialization of `X` with template arguments corresponding to the template parameters from the respective function template where, for each template parameter `PP` in the template parameter list of the function template, a corresponding template argument `AA` is formed. If `PP` declares a parameter pack, then `AA` is the pack expansion `PP...` ([temp.variadic]); otherwise, `AA` is the *id-expression* `PP`.
>
> If the rewrite produces an invalid type, then `P` is not at least as specialized as `A`.

Which means that to verify if `Foo<Bar>` itself is okay, we synthesize:

```
template <decltype(auto) I> struct X;

template <auto I>           void __f(X<I> ); // P
template <decltype(auto) I> void __f(X<I> ); // A
```

All the types here are valid (so the last statement doesn't apply). Now, typically when we do partial ordering it's in the context of either overload resolution or picking a class template specialization, in which case what we're looking for is the ["more specialized"](http://eel.is/c++draft/over#match.best-1.7) function template, where `F` is [more specialized than](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#10) `G` if `F` is at least as specialized as `G` and `G` is not at least as specialized as `F`.

But in this context, we don't care about which is more specialized. We only need `P` to be at least as specialized as `A`. All that means that deduction has to succeed from `A` to `P`. So if we synthesize some unique type `U` with some value `V`, can we deduce `X<I>` from `X<V>`? Yes. Hence, `P` is at least as specialized as `A`, so the template-argument `Bar` matches the template-parameter `TT`.

---

Now, passing that point, I'd say this a clang bug. The template *template-parameter* is `template <auto>`, which is what we should use to validate the expression. With a non-type template parameter `auto`, we'd try to use `x` as a value - but `x` isn't a valid constant expression, so this should fail. clang appears to be using `template <decltype(auto) >` directly - which I'm not sure is valid.

That said, I'm not sure this case has even been considered - I don't see any wording one way or the other and it's worth raising an issue.